# Facebook newAppSession() stops execution

Tags: php, facebook

After the assignment `$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();`, my app stops executing without error or warning.

I have reduced the code for simplify

```php
<?php
session_start();

$br = '<br>';
echo ' session start '.$br;
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' ); 
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
//require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
echo ' require ok '.$br;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
//use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
//use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
//use Facebook\FacebookRequest; 
//use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
//use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
//use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
//use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
//use Facebook\GraphObject;

echo ' use ok '.$br;

$appid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxx';

echo ' assegnati id e secret '.$br;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appid ,$secret);
echo ' define FB session '.$br;
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
echo ' session ok? '.$br;

?>
```

The echo is only for debug. The `echo ' session ok? '` is not displayed.

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Comment: I just looked, in the facebook page developer is all confused, but accessing the server error that occurs is 'network error: 500 Internal server error'

Comment: ok! it's work! server permission problem. thanks